# Distribute a strictly client-side app as one file

Tags: html, client, file-generation

So I am trying to develop a browser based 'app' that is similar to a catalog. The user can place orders and view items on this page. Right now it is made up of an HTML page, a CSS sheet, some Javascript and some PHP. Unfortunately this app can not be hosted on a server, and will the files will be directly sent to the user.

I don't want to directly send all of my code to the user, I want to make things simpler (and more hidden) by compiling all these scripts/sheets into one file that the user can just open in their browser.

I've considered doing the scripts and sheets inside inline HTML, but inline script have too many drawbacks and are bad practice.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Should I not worry about it and make sure to instruct the user just to open up the HTML file?

Thanks.

Comment: there are several static site generation tools available :) they may be of interest to you.  (I'm sure the community may have a ton of recommendations/opinions about which ones are best ... but that gets off topic of stackoverflow)  If there's no hosting, you'll definitely need to flatten out the PHP into HTML ... and if you want to include CSS + JS in separate files, they will still need to be shipped (unless you can point to a CDN for them?)

Comment: conventionally, many developers try to separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript -- but conventionally, websites are served from a hosted environment.  You're in untraditional waters, breaking conventions to best match your use case is totally acceptable.

Comment: if there is not a lot of interactivity (JS), I would recommend trying to see if you could instead send your users PDFs (if a PDF can meet most/all of your requirements).

Comment: @Doug thanks for the great advice. Unfortunately(?) there is a lot of interactivity and a PDF definitely will not cut it. Is it possible to have a private CDN? I'm writing the JS+CSS myself and I don't necessarily want to be public, but that seems like the cleanest option. I'll look into it in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: You can get a web server without a domain name... It won't be really private (still needs to be accessible by the content you deliver) but slim to no chance any human will find your stuff at http:// 123.45.678.90/scripts.js

Comment: You are right- thanks for the help!